# Am I Scrambling my data when writing to netCDF?

Tags: netcdf4

I have created a 2D array that when plotted looks like this:

[image: 2D array of data with range of 0 to 1.2 and includes NaNs]

Basically it is an array of size [101,365] of numbers with range from 0.0 to 1.2 and contains NaNs.

I am writing it to a netCDF4 file in this manner:

```
nc_out = Dataset(nc_out_file, 'w', format='NETCDF4')

#Create Dimemsions
y = nc_out.createDimension('y',101)
x = nc_out.createDimension('x',365)

#Create Variables
latitudes = nc_out.createVariable('latitude', np.float32, ('y'))
days = nc_out.createVariable('days', np.float32,('x'))
on2_climo = nc_out.createVariable('on2_climo', np.float32, ('x', 'y'))

#Fill Variables
latitudes[:] = lat
days[:] = day
on2_climo[:] = data

nc_out.close()
```

However, when I plot the data I've saved in the file it looks nothing like the original data:

[image: Scrambled Data?]

What is going on here?  The faint diagonal lines make me think there is something weird going on here...

Is there a better way to code a netCDF4 file?  I'd share a copy of the original data with you... but I can't seem to get a faithful version of it saved...

Comment: what is the original data type and shape of `data`?

Comment: The data is shaped 101 by 365.  It is originally float32 data type.

Comment: looks weird indeed... can you reproduce this behavior if you create some dummy input for `data`? And did you make sure to have all the requirements listed [here](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) installed (e.g. HDF5 lib)?